# Retrieve SAVED objectID from Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

Im trying to retrieve the `objectId` of my parse records.  I can save and retrieve data ok, but having gone through all parse documents, Google, and SO, I can't seem to get a clear answer on how to get the `id` for accessing records before the main block without hard coding the `objectId` as in the tutorial from Parse.

`getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"SS8Cw7rT1h"` <-------- Trying to retrieve `object id` to go here

Im **saving** data to parse inc `objectId` here (all good)

```
PFObject *scheme = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"SchemeProvider"];

//Sections of class
scheme[@"schemeName"] = self.schemeName.text;
scheme[@"schemeRegistrationNumber"] = self.registrationNumber.text;

//Save then get object id of saved row
[scheme saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

    [scheme objectId];
     NSLog(@"SCHEME ROW ID %@",[scheme objectId]);



}];
```

**Retrieving** from parse (all good) - except - can't get `objectID` before main block

```
PFQuery *queryScheme = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SchemeProvider"];

//NSString *myobjectId = [queryScheme valueForKey:@"objectId"]; <------trying to retrive object id

[queryScheme getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"SS8Cw7rT1h" block:^(PFObject *retrivedData, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"All data = %@", retrivedData);

}];
```

Answer (score 3):

I have just hit this problem and have an example for you in swift

There is a function that saves with a block in background

You can access the objectId while saving in the block thats run after saving it to the cloud

```
var foo = PFObject(className:"Foo")
foo["bar"] = "something"
foo.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(){(succeeded: Bool!, error:NSError!) in

   if succeeded
   {
       self.fooLabel.text = foo.objectId
   }
}
```

You could store the objectId for a certain object e.g in a data structure or with core data if you need it for later access

Otherwise you need to query the object with property values i guess

like seen here: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-basic/iOS

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, ive already got the `objectId` saved using the block method, trying to read it out is the issue

Comment: The block method is the way forward to get `obj id`, ive updated my code as my code wasn't quite right there, think saving the object id to NSSUser defaults will do unless anyone else has a cleaner way.  Thanks for the swift code, useful.  upvoted